# How to edit content search webpart in master page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have a content search webpart in our masterpage. Since the application is developed by third party .. i dont have any clue how to edit it :( I want to edit the query of the webpart and change it in such a way that it points to my new url.

When i try to edit page , those webparts are not in editable format.

Please guide how to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

How it looks like in SharePoint Designer editable mode? Whether there is in masterpage file any similar tag `<WebControls:ContentBySearchWebPart/>`?